# jQuery keyup filter working when content is in columns, but not when float: left;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Running into a problem where after you type something into the input (type in "spore" then delete it), the boxes do not reset to the 2x4 (instead there are 6 on top, 2 below). It works if I put the boxes into 4 columns, but not if I just do float: left on #sortables.

Here is the fiddle that works (with columns): http://jsfiddle.net/SkQPZ/1

Here is the fiddle that doesn't work (with float): http://jsfiddle.net/4pBFu/.  I would like this fiddle to work.

Below is my jQuery.

```
    (function ($) {
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

function listFilter(gamefilter, list) {
    var form = $("<form>").attr({
        "class": "filterform",
            "action": "#"
    }),
        input = $("<input>").attr({
            "class": "filterinput",
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "Filter"

        });

    $(form).append(input).appendTo(gamefilter);
    $(input).change(function () {
        var list = $("#sortable");
        var filter = $(this).val();
        console.log(filter.length);
        if (filter.length > 0) {
            $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
            $(".number").hide();
            $(".numberstwo").hide();

        } else {
            console.log($(".number"));
            $(".number").show();
            $(".numberstwo").show();
            $(list).find("a").parent().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    }).keyup(function () {
        $(this).change();

    });
}
$(function () {
    listFilter($("#gamefilter"), $("#sortable"));

});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: As I see, it's working correctly !

Answer (score 1):

Dont know what you are trying to do exactly, so I did this with your "broken" jsfiddle
Is it what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/4pBFu/8/

Essentially, I added this in the if to display items that do meet the filter after remove some text.

```
$(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().show();
```